# Opencart 'cart' button

Tags: opencart

In OpenCart template is a file template/common/header.tpl in this file you can find

```
<?php echo $cart; ?>
```

this code displays your cart state.
Where I can go in order to modify $cart ? 
( there is no file template/module/cart.tpl )

Comment: Deja vu? I think there was the very same question today already which was closed. **If it was closed it was closed from certain reasons**. That mean if you delete it and ask the same question again, it will be closed again. And again. Until you think about what is wrong here and you'll find out that the question is wrong. Or the problem description insufficient. Or something else. So, please, pay attention to the HELP (top right) section and about how to ask good questions.

Comment: It isn't the same question.

Comment: I would put my hand to fire it is...

Comment: @shadyyx is not going to get burned at all here. Your [original question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23973885/opencart-cart-button) is *exactly the same*, word-for-word, as what you posted here. And of course you know that, since you posted this *one minute after* deleting that one. Please don't post duplicates like this. Instead, improve your original.

Comment: Oh my god! My original question was DIFFERENT! After my original question was closed, I edited it, but it was NOT reopen so I posted it again as a new question. Look at question history, it WAS DIFFERENT!

Comment: @Zhigalin, In any case this is an OpenCart question and belongs to http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/77558/opencart not on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your source > catalog > view > theme > default (your theme) > template > module > & then find cart.tpl file.

Comment: Where is no file with such name.

Comment: are you default theme use? Please Go to catalog > view > theme > default > template > module > & then Here, You can see cart.tpl file.

Comment: No, I am not. My theme(ancart) does not contain this file.
I guess I have to search in controller/common/header.php but I can't find anything.

Comment: I have updated Our answer. please follow & check.

Comment: There is no such file.

Comment: are you which OpenCart version using?

Comment: I can not say. why not available in your theme? but, You can see. it is file available in default OpenCart theme.